# How do I delete only the selected data?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js

When I select a user and an item that a user is using and press the button, I want only that item to disappear. However, the code I created now removes all items the User has.

When adding selected data, I inserted and saved using .add and .save. But I don't know how to delete and save it.

-- spring boot (controller)

```
@PutMapping(value = {"/users/{id}", "/profileModi/{id}", "/users/productSetting/{id}"})
public ResponseEntity<User> updateUser(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody User user) {
  Optional<User> userData = userRepository.findById(id);

  if (userData.isPresent()) {
    User _user = userData.get();
    _user.setProductInfo(user.getProductInfo());
    _user.setRoles(user.getRoles());
    _user.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    _user.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    _user.setPassword(user.getPassword());
    _user.setDelYn(user.isDelYn());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userRepository.save(_user), HttpStatus.OK);
  } else {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }
}
```

-- vue.js

```
      <b-button variant="danger" class="btn btn-fw"
        @click="updateProductUser()"
      >
        cancle
      </b-button>
```

--vue.js (script)

```
updateProductUser() {
  var data = {
    id:this.currentUser.id,
    email:this.currentUser.email,
    delYn:this.currentUser.delYn,
    password:this.currentUser.password,
    username:this.currentUser.username,
    roles:this.currentUser.roles
  };
  ProductSettingUserDataService.update(this.currentUser.id, data)
    .then(response => {
      this.currentUser = response.data;
      console.log(this.currentUser);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
},
```

Originally, there was a productInfo table in the User table, and I used a simple method of deleting data by not writing this table. But now I only want to delete one of the data of the productInfo I have selected.

Can you tell which code should be inserted in the controller to be deleted and saved?

I also tried with @DeleteMapping. But it failed...

[Relationship table between user and product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLnJZ.png)

As you can see in the picture, User and productInfo have a 1:n relationship. For example, I want to delete only product_id = 12 out of 3 products with user_id = 1.

++ users Table
[users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHi1d.png)

++ productInfo Table
[productInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWBwp.png)

The productInfo table exists in the users table.

++ console window
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKIn2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is replacing all the data from the **user** and your `vue.js`script is not sending product data:

```
// Data sent by the front
var data = {
 id:this.currentUser.id,
 email:this.currentUser.email,
 delYn:this.currentUser.delYn,
 password:this.currentUser.password,
 username:this.currentUser.username,
 roles:this.currentUser.roles
};

// Controller PUT
 User _user = userData.get();
 // The front is not sending any productInfo
_user.setProductInfo(user.getProductInfo());

_user.setRoles(user.getRoles());
_user.setUsername(user.getUsername());
_user.setEmail(user.getEmail());
_user.setPassword(user.getPassword());
_user.setDelYn(user.isDelYn());
return new ResponseEntity<>(userRepository.save(_user), HttpStatus.OK);
```

Since you are not sending product info, the previous product info is deleted. Your front need to send the product info data that you want to preserve.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer :) 
User table and ProductInfo table have a 1:N relationship. The user has multiple products, and I asked a question because I wanted to delete only the product I selected. The code I've created now deletes all products in the user table. 
Photos and descriptions have been added.

Comment: Oh I see, let me change my answer

Comment: I put the productInfo in the var data and tried to run it, but not only the selected product as before, but all the products in the user are deleted. How should I add it to the controller?

Comment: I don't understand the difference. In your first comment you were saying that you wanted to delete only the selected product and the problem was all the products being deleted and now you changed something and all the products (the same as before apparently) are being deleted, so what is the change between the two of them?? Also if you changed your original code, can you edit the question with the new code

Comment: If what I understand is correct, add var data = {productInfo: this.currentUser.productInfo} to the front. And the grammar to control this in the controller is _user.setProductInfo(user.getProductInfo()); Put it in front. Is that right? 
If this is correct, I didn't understand what the grammar to control was...

Answer (score 0):

let me see user table's data. i guess that your userInfo and your productInfo share one table; If you have a productinfo table, you shoud transfer a productId from vue  page instead of userId

Comment: Should I change the vue code, not the controller code? I don't know how to change it. Please help.

Comment: yes. let me see your user table and productInfo table

Comment: Added users table, productInfo table, and console picture. Can you check it?

Comment: I can not see picture.  you say :  'User and productInfo have a 1:n relationship'  and  'The productInfo table exists in the users table.'       This is  not a good idea, userid should be added in productInfo table. Because one user have mutilple productInfo. User table contains only user info